# How to print values passed by client in tensorflow federated?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-federated

I am trying to understand tensorflow federated. I was referring to https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/tutorials/custom_federated_algorithms_2#gradient_descent_on_a_sequence_of_local_data site. Here I am not understanding how to print the values of passed by each client in this function?

```
SERVER_FLOAT_TYPE = tff.FederatedType(tf.float32, tff.SERVER, all_equal=True)

@tff.federated_computation(
    SERVER_MODEL_TYPE, SERVER_FLOAT_TYPE, CLIENT_DATA_TYPE)
def federated_train(model, learning_rate, data):
  return tff.federated_mean(
      tff.federated_map(
          local_train,
          [tff.federated_broadcast(model),
           tff.federated_broadcast(learning_rate),
           data]))
```

and also can anybody tell me what is the use of tff.sequence_reduce.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to inspect the values on clients here, there are a few ways you could imagine doing so.

One would be to use a `tf.print` op inside of `local_train`, if that function is a `tff.tf_computation`, which I believe is not the case here.

Another would be to pull the function calls out a little more, so instead of writing `tff.federated_mean(tff.federated_map(local_train...))`

We might write

```
train_results_on_clients = tff.federated_map(local_train...)
aggregated_result =tff.federated_mean(train_results_on_clients)
```

Then, if the outer function returns both of these values, the value materialized in the Python runtime representing `train_results_on_clients` will be the results of running a single round of training at all clients, presented as a list with one entry per client; TFF allows you to do this in the same way you may inspect intermediate values of a function by returning them.

One thing that will *not* work is inserting a Python print statement inside the federated computation; this will only get executed at tracing time, for the same reasons that one must use `tf.print` instead of Python print inside of TF graphs (at least, with no autograph).

As for `tff.sequence_reduce`, its purpose is really to demonstrate the local-computation-agnostic design of TFF; point being, a model training loop can be written in a way that is completely agnostic to TensorFlow as a local computation engine.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for help. I want to know the values passed by each client, therefore I tried to pull the function call and wrote it as `train_results_on_clients = tff.federated_map(local_train...)
aggregated_result =tff.federated_mean(train_results_on_clients)` and  I have used tf.print for train_results_on_clients but I am getting the following error

Comment: `tf.print` will not work inside a federated computation context; only inside of a function decorated as a `tff.tf_computation` will `tf.print` do anything good. Your other option here is to *return* `train_results_on_clients` from the Python function; this is what i would recommend